# Segmentation fault during memory allocation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

Why I get an "Segmentation-Fault"-Error for `data[2]` and (probably) `data[3]`?
To the first two pointer I can assign memory without any problems, and I think I have allocated enough memory for four pointers. Can somebody please give me a hint?

```
void test(char ***data)
{
*data = (char **) malloc(4 * sizeof(char *));
*data[0] = (char *) malloc(100);
*data[1] = (char *) malloc(100);
*data[2] = (char *) malloc(100);
*data[3] = (char *) malloc(100);
}
char **data=NULL;
test(&data);
```

Comment: There must be lots of hard-to-find duplicates, but... `(*data)[0] = malloc...` will fix the problem.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` output..

Comment: Here we go - I found a pretty close duplicate. If you find a better duplicate, click the top-edit link, and use [add-original] button to include a link as well.

Comment: Brackets bind before stars: you probably mean `(*data)[0]` rather than `*data[0]`. But that being said, if you think you ever need `***` for a real problem, you probably don't understand it correctly.